# Make electron app compatible with El Capitan

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am new to Electron, but the app I packaged (using `electron-packager`) for MacOS works fine on 10.12.X and 10.13.X but not on 10.10.5.

Is there a way to make it compatible with `El Capitan 10.10.5` as well?

When I try to run the application, I get an error

```
Check with the developer to make sure SimpleMath works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't do this.

Because they only support from version 10.11.6. I already tried this a lot of time.

But, I can't find any solution for that thing.

Comment: Go to the Git page .They said the same thing.I have suffering from this issue for the past one year

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is answered in official documentation here:

[Build Instructions (macOS)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-macos.md#macos-sdk)

the document also states:

> ...
>   Official Electron builds are built with Xcode 9.4.1, and the macOS 10.13 SDK.
>   ...

Comment: Vladimir's link is outdated (broken), this is the updated link: [Build Instructions macOS](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-macos.md#macos-sdk)